# Javascript: validation for mobile number with paste option

Tags: javascript

I am working in Javascript. I am trying to make a function on the `keypress` event. I want to make function for validation on mobile number. I want to allow only digits in it. I also want to allow *ctrl+v* and *ctrl+a* in this but I dont want to allow V and A as characters.

I have seen many answers here but no one is purely same.

Comment: Do you just want to make sure only digits are entered, or do you want to check a certain pattern as well, like: `555-555-5555` ?

Comment: I just want to enter digits only. but i also want to make functionality of paste(ctrl+v), please focus on this ctrl+v functionality. i have done only digit functionality.

Comment: See answers to this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904763/javascript-jquery-numeric-input-keycode-for-3-and-are-the-same/8905112#8905112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care that digits are entered, as it seems from your question, this Jquery code will work.

It uses on `keyup()` and thus it will work on `ctrl+v` as well. It won't work if someone uses right-click to paste, and for that reason, you can just disable right clicking on that field.

It works by stripping off the last character of the input value if it is not a number. So if a user enters 25s or 25ss, it will get stripped down to 25.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nz9tC/8/)**

**The Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#number').keyup(function(){    
        var input = this.value;
        while (isNaN(input))
        {
            input = input.substring(0,input.length-1);
            $('#number').val(input);             
        }
    });
    //disable right click on the field
    $('#number').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `$('#number').bind('input propertychange', function() ...` to catch all methods of input. Great little trick to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 input tags which use the pattern attribute.

```
<form>
    <input name="name" value="" pattern="\d+" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please refrain from using caps lock in answers (or questions for that matter)

Comment: This didn't work for me in any browsers. Are you sure your syntax is correct? http://jsfiddle.net/ayR3h/

Comment: @mrtsherman this works when you enclose it in a form (I edited my answer to match this)